# IF CONDITION doesn't work between Popup accept and another Element, just 1 of them works. Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, popup

I am trying to do if else condition for Selenium Python with popup.

i am checking a website, sometimes appears popup to make sure that u want start the TASK.

and sometimes appears the Button direct without Popup.

i want the code to switch to popup and click it if its appears and click the button if not.

Here is my 2 Tries to make it.

```
if  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click()

else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

in this example he just run the first IF condition and doesn't turn to Else if he didn't match the IF.it just click the button if it appears, if not it will crash without go to the else.

```
if  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present()):
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click
```

in this try he run also just the first IF Condition if found it and doesn't go to the else.
also here he is running just the popup click, if it appers.

when it crashed, there is no a message reason. Selenium python mistake is empty

Can Someone help me?

Comment: if it times out webdriverwait will throw an exception of Timeout... so try/catch the call.  The catch part would contain your else logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `try-except` as following:

```py
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click()
except:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to fix this :

1. `find_elements` :

**Sample code :**

```
if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "buttonStartNew"))) > 0 :
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click()
else:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

2. `try-catch:`

just wrapped inside `try-except`

```
try:
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "buttonStartNew"))) > 0 :
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click()
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: The both Comments are right, thank you for ur help, but i solved it with another one:                       try:
        time.sleep(7)
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

    except:
        botton_to_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'buttonStartNew'))).click()

Comment: Did you try with `find_elements` ? I believe that should help you as well.